# How to fail my Ant build if findBugs target find bugs

Tags: java, ant, findbugs

I want to start findBugs on existing project (on command line there are currently 522 bugs).

How can I set in the ant file (under findbugs target) the option to fail the build if there are more than 522 bugs found?

I want to actually fail the ant build and not to understanf it manually from the output report.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using a build server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That may not be possible. You can use data mining task and do some special handling. http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/datamining.html

Comment: Thanks, it really not straight-forward - I'll find external way of doin that.

Comment: Ant is extensible, with Java code.  While it might not be a straightforward task to someone just getting into Ant's internals, there is nothing impossible in Ant, unless it is also impossible in Java.

Answer (score 1):

This may go a bit too far, but I'm adding it as an answer none the less.

You can use [sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/) for that. Sonar is a free platform to measure and track code quality. It has findbugs metrics included.

It has the [Build Breaker Plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Build+Breaker), which will break your build on certain conditions.

Comment: +1 Agreed. Sonar is easy to integrate into build and well worth adding to the build process.

Answer (score 1):

[You need to write a custom ant task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-writing-tasks.html), deriving from Ant's `Task` base class, which adds a log listener that sets a property and removes itself afterwards.  The custom task will fetch the current [`Project` and add the log listener via addLogListener(...)](http://api.dpml.net/ant/1.6.5/org/apache/tools/ant/Project.html).

The log listener needs to identify when findBugs is logging, discern which log message is the one that lists the number of bugs, parse that line, set the property and remove itself from the set of log listeners.

Once you have that task, [you need to also write a new condition](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/custom-programming.html#customconditions), as Ant doesn't ship with a numeric comparison condition.  Then you can use your custom condition in the fail task, like any other condition.

```
<findBugCountListener prefix="findbugs.count"/>
<findBugs ...>
</findBugs>
<fail>
  <condition property="allupper">
    <and>
      <isset property="findbugs.count"/>
      <greaterThan value="${findbugs.count}" limit="522"/>
    </and>
  </condition>
</fail>
```

Ideally your listener will then set an Ant property, with the number of bugs.  You can then use AntContrib's Assert task to throw a build exception if the number of bugs is too high.

Yes, it is more manual work than simply configuring a few tags, but at least it is possible with Ant due to it's ability to load custom extensions.  It isn't like Ant was written with explicit knowledge of the findBugs plugin (which naturally had to be written afterwards).

Another alternative is to find the source code of the findBugs ANT plugin, and assuming it has a license that allows legal modification, modify the ANT plugin to have a new "additional" property, `setCount="propName"` and then capture and set the property within the existing findBugs ANT plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Quite an old question, but maybe this is useful for someone else: There *is* a rather simple way to achieve the desired behavior by setting the `warningsProperty` attribute of the `findbugs` task and afterwards letting `fail` check for the property's value:

```
<findbugs ... warningsProperty="findbugs.warnings">
  ...
</findbugs>
<fail>
  <condition><istrue value="${findbugs.warnings}"/></condition>
</fail>
```

(Needless to say that findbugs is abandoned now, but there is [spotbugs](https://spotbugs.github.io/) as a successor.)